# Looking for something similar to Time Machine for windows 10

Tags: windows-10, backup, disk-image

I have been an apple user for several years. Recently I have purchuased a computer that runs Windows 10 and I can't find a program similar to what Time Machine does in mac. The features I look for are:

- Make a complete disk image back-up while I can work on the computer.
- Be able to use the program on different hard drives.
- I could use a different computer to obtain different versions of files in the hard drive.
- In case of emergency: ❶ Be able to buy a new computer; ❷ Install a program or run commands to make a exact copy of my computer in the new one. ❸ Be able to work on this computer without noticing is different.
- Be able to do the above process in a few clicks.

Is it possible to have the above?

If needed I would pay for the service.

If know Windows 10 includes File History and a Backup program but as far as my experience is not the same..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give a try to a close Windows alternative [Macrium reflect free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)

Features include:

- Full image backups
- Differential Images backup (for faster backups and reduced storage space).
- Incremental backups
- **Scheduled backups**
- Macrium Reflect supports backup to local, network **and USB drives (external drives** as well as burning to all DVD formats.

Answer (score 2):

[Genie Timeline](https://www.genie9.com/home/Genie_Timeline_Home/overview.aspx) is my favorite; lots of features and easy to use. You can read their long list of features at the provided link. You can read a review of Genie Timeline and 5 other backup solutions [here](https://beebom.com/time-machine-alternatives-windows/).